# How to iterate over a vec of structs as tuples?

Tags: rust

Playground [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=34ec5a8cb5f8288c9b124489a661757a):

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let instance = BoundPair {
        actual: Bound { x: 2, y: 3 },
        scaled: ScaledBound {
            bound: Bound { x: 2, y: 3 },
            scale: -3,
        },
    };

    // This structure can be effectively aliased to simplify access
    //  (allowing `b` instead of `instance.b.a` in this case)
    // This allows the struct to preserve and illustrate the clear structure,
    //  while making access just a little easier.
    let (a, b, c) = <(&Bound, &Bound, i32)>::from(&instance);
    // In practical usage where the types could be inferred
    //  this from could simply be `instance.into();`.

    println!("struct: {:.?}", instance);
    println!("tuple: {:.?}", (a, b, c));

    // This also works
    let vec = vec![instance.clone(), instance.clone(), instance.clone()];
    for (a, b, c) in vec.iter().map(Into::into) {
        println!("tuple: {:.?}", (a, b, c));
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct BoundPair {
    actual: Bound,
    scaled: ScaledBound,
}

impl<'a> From<&'a BoundPair> for (&'a Bound, &'a Bound, i32) {
    fn from(x: &'a BoundPair) -> Self {
        (&x.actual, &x.scaled.bound, x.scaled.scale)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Bound {
    x: usize,
    y: usize,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct ScaledBound {
    bound: Bound,
    scale: i32,
}
```

I have a complex struct, for making access a little easier and direct I have:

```rust
impl<'a> From<&'a BoundPair> for (&'a Bound, &'a Bound,i32) {
    fn from(x: &'a BoundPair) -> Self {
        (&x.actual, &x.scaled.bound, x.scaled.scale)
    }
}
```

This allows instead of having to write for instance `bound_pair.scaled.bound` each time to simply write `scaled_bound` (or `scaled`). In contexts where doing a lot of comparisons and operations simplifying the name used for me personally makes the code rather more readable.

It simply requires a prerequisite:

```rust
let (actual,scaled,scale) = &bound_pair.into();
```

(in the playground I use `let (a,b,c) = <(&Bound,&Bound,i32)>::from(&instance);` since its not used so the types cannot be inferred).

For a more complex case I would like to be able to do:

```rust
// Given `vec` is Vec<BoundPair>
for (a,b,c) in vec.iter() {
    println!("tuple: {:.?}",(a,b,c));
}
```

I know I can do:

```rust
for (a,b,c) in vec.iter().map(<(&Bound,&Bound,i32)>::from) {
    println!("tuple: {:.?}",(a,b,c));
}
```

but this is a little awkward.

Is there a trait to implement that would allow functionality similar to the first approach for iterating?

Comment: "but this is rather awkward." why ? just why ? "Is there a trait to implement that would allow functionality similar to the first approach for iterating?" implement from... wait you did.

Comment: You can replace `<(&Bound,&Bound,i32)>::from` with `Into::into`, which is less verbose.

Comment: @AlphaModder That's definitely better, thank you. Iif you reckon that's the closest I can get, feel free drop that as answer (sometimes questions and answers basic).

Comment: Also working: [`<_>::from`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=28003618dd955d32bda3966b606ee533)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write out the full type if you replace `<(&Bound,&Bound,i32)>::from` with `Into::into` in the `map` call.

Comment: since the question never explain what was wrong with `<(&Bound,&Bound,i32)>::from` you just answer a bad question by guessing. make it a meh answer

Comment: @Stargateur Initially this was a comment for exactly that reason, I made it an answer at OP's request.